# Call Symfony API Platform custom filters from within the application

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I have built custom filters on API Platform w/ Symfony. I'm writing a command that needs to use these filters. I think making an API call from within the application isn't a clean way to do it and duplicating the functionality by writing query builders seems dumb.

Anyone know how to grab the data from within the Symfony application i.e. from a command or a controller?

Obviously I could just hit the endpoint, and this works fine, but it seems wrong to get data into one part of the app from another via an HTTP call.